# MS SQL Server Function using Interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, date

Hey there I have a Function trying to convert it from Oracle to MS SQL but I get incorrect syntax near '1' one line 7:

```
IF @nPaysQuarterly = 0 BEGIN
     -- If the base date is less than March 1st of the given year then the due date is for that year
     -- Else the due date is for the year plus 1
        If @dBaseDate < convert(DATETIME, '01-Mar-'+isnull(year(@dBaseDate), '')) BEGIN
            SET @dDueDate = convert(DATETIME, '01-Mar-'+isnull(year(@dBaseDate), ''));
        END
        ELSE BEGIN SET @dDueDate = convert(DATETIME, '01-Mar-'+isnull(year(@dBaseDate), '')) + interval '1' year;
        END 
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dAnnualDue1) BEGIN
          SET @dDueDate = @dAnnualDue1;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dFirstQuarterDue) BEGIN
          SET @dDueDate = @dFirstQuarterDue;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dSecondQuarterDue) BEGIN
          SET @dDueDate = @dSecondQuarterDue;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dThirdQuarterDue) BEGIN
          SET @dDueDate = @dThirdQuarterDue;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dAnnualDue) BEGIN
          SET @dDueDate = @dAnnualDue;
    END 

    RETURN AIP.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(@dDueDate) ;
END;
```

Anything wrong when adding 1 increment to the year ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is the query you are looking for

```
IF (@nPaysQuarterly = 0 )
BEGIN
     -- If the base date is less than March 1st of the given year then the due date is for that year
     -- Else the due date is for the year plus 1
        If (@dBaseDate < convert(DATETIME, '01-Mar-'+isnull(year(@dBaseDate), '')))
            BEGIN
                SET @dDueDate = convert(DATETIME, '01-Mar-'+isnull(year(@dBaseDate), ''));
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                SET @dDueDate = DATEADD(year,1,convert(DATETIME, '01-Mar-'+isnull(year(@dBaseDate), '')));
            END 

    IF (@dBaseDate < @dAnnualDue1) 
          SET @dDueDate = @dAnnualDue1;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dFirstQuarterDue) 
          SET @dDueDate = @dFirstQuarterDue;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dSecondQuarterDue) 
          SET @dDueDate = @dSecondQuarterDue;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dThirdQuarterDue) 
          SET @dDueDate = @dThirdQuarterDue;
    ELSE IF (@dBaseDate < @dAnnualDue) 
          SET @dDueDate = @dAnnualDue;
    END 

    RETURN AIP.GETNEXTBUSINESSDAY(@dDueDate) ;
END;
```

you have to use `DATEADD` Function to add one year to your datetime value. another Issue is that you cannot start an `IF` Statement with an `ELSE IF`

Comment: Thank you it went smooth, now I get a convertion error at another line for date convertion at the beginning in declarations:

`DECLARE @dAnnualDue1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @nYear, '') +'/03/1';`

any idea what this brought up ?

error says: Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function.

Comment: Use `convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4) + '/03/01')` instead of it

Comment: I use it:     `DECLARE @dAnnualDue1 DATETIME =  convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4) + '/03/01');` but get error syntax at '+',

Comment: `convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) + '/03/01')` missed one `)`

Comment: It is better to write dates with the following format `yyyyMMdd` because it is sql server universal. `convert(Datetime,Cast(@nYear as varchar(4)) + '0301')`